# How to get sum of numeric value in Array of string in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have an array of strings which contain numeric values negative as well as positive:

```
NSArray *myNumbers = @[@"0.0454", @"-1.3534", @"0.345",
                             @"65", @"-0.345", @"1.35"];
```

How can I find the sum of all numeric value from this array of string?

Is there any default method or workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

It's simple with `valueForKeyPath`:

```
NSArray *myNumbers = @[@"0.0454", @"-1.3534", @"0.345",
         @"65", @"-0.345", @"1.35"];
NSNumber *sum = [myNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
NSLog(@"%@", sum); // 65.042
```

You could also loop through the array, but the above is easiest.

Comment: does it work for string values in array? or its only for numeric values in array?

Comment: Those are string values; but you could also use floats, or integers, etc.

Comment: actually i am getting array with string values, and i think this method only work for numeric values

Comment: i have mention in question "array of string" :)

Comment: You are using strings! `@"666.666"` = string, `@666.666` = float. **BOTH WORK!**

Comment: NO, It will not work for string, have you tried by your own, I have tried

Comment: I tried this and `sum` is `NSDecimalNumber` 65.042.